# whatsapp from old phone to be used in new phone in different country

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I was living in Syria in middle east, and I'm visiting USA.
I still have my phone with whatsapp installed using my Syrian's number, then I bought a new phone Samsung S7, and I removed SIM card from old phone to my new phone.
I installed Whatsapp in my new phone and put my Syrian number with area code and wasn't able to get the verification code to activate whatsapp in the new phone.

is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes

- Enabling roaming to receive verification
- Through voice mail

See [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/30025981) for details